# To perform linear interpolation between two images using lerp

Tags: c++, opencv, interpolation

I have to use lerp function to interpolate two images .the post [How to perform a linear interpolation between to images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479269/how-to-perform-a-linear-interpolation-between-to-images)  recommended this method dst[x][y].r = lerp(factor, src1[x][y].r, src2[x][y].r) but i am unable to get required results as i get errors of using [ ,] brackets can anyone suggest a better  way in open cv C++

Comment: Can you show the code where you're having the issue?  That code looks ok, but it is dependent on what `dst`, `src`, and `src2` are.

Comment: I believe, `dst`, `src` and `src2` are `Mat`s. You cannot access a `Mat` using [x][y] syntax. The equivalent would be `src1.at<uchar>(y, x)`. Note, however, that this works only for CV_8UC1 images. For another type, you should specify something else than `uchar`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want the following lerp function:

```
src1*(1-factor)+src2*factor;
```

It can be implemented in OpenCV like this:

```
cv::Mat src1, src2; // These two images have to be the same size and type 
cv::Mat result;
double factor = 0.5; // [0, 1]
cv::addWeighted(src1, 1.0-factor, src2, factor, 0.0, result);
```